# How do I check if my income taxes were filed?

Tags: taxes, income-tax

How can I find out if my estranged husband filed our taxes.  He said he did, but I don't trust him.

Comment: Call the IRS.  This time of year they are much less busy.

Comment: Are you in the U.S.?

Comment: Did he file electronically or on paper? If on paper, and you didn't sign anything, then no, your taxes haven't been filed properly. Both spouses must sign. If electronically, then both spouses must enter a PIN, but he could have done that on his own. http://www.dontmesswithtaxes.com/2015/10/both-spouses-must-sign-joint-return-or-pay-tax-penalties.html

Comment: Why the down vote? This is a direct, non obvious, very personal financial question.

Comment: It isn't obvious because the answer would depend on the country; which after 20 hours is still undermined. Once the country has been established the question might even be a duplicate.

Comment: I'm in favor of a 24 hour grace period. Just as we expect a new member to not comment "where's my answer?" when only a bit of time has passed, I think it's reasonable to give any question that just needs clarification a day for the OP to return and update.

Answer (score 1):

You can request a [transcript](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Tax-Return-Transcript-Types-and-Ways-to-Order-Them) online to get a report of the high level totals; in case you would prefer a full photocopy of the return for your records, fill out and mail in Form 4506 available at that link.  The full photocopy has a fee of $50.

IRS availability info:

> If you filed your tax return electronically, it takes about 3 weeks before a transcript becomes available. If you mailed your tax return, it takes about 6 weeks. If you didn’t pay all the tax you owe, your transcript may not be available until mid-May, or a week after you pay the full amount owed. Refer to Transcript Availability for more information.

Comment: This (obviously) assumes the OP is in the U.S. Reasonable but not certain.